# Windows 10 won't boot, primary partition has become RAW

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, mbr, diskpart

My Dell 5559 laptop shutdown suddenly due to power outage. After that, when I tried to turn it on, it gave an error:

```
A disk read error occured
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

I have been looking at all sorts of solutions for this but seem to hit a wall with every single one.

The SSD drive is recognized when I go to Boot options > System information. Here the volume and its capacity are listed correctly.

I made a bootable USB with Windows 10 ISO and booted the laptop using this. Went to Repair windows option > Command prompt.

When I enter `diskpart` command and then use list disk, the SSD disk is listed as:

```
Disk 0   Online   119 GB
```

Here I have tried several options.

1. Tried `chkdsk /f` but it doesn't work since my primary partition where Windows has been installed has turned to RAW.
2. Tried `bootrec /fixmbr` but it says that `The system cannot find the file specified`.
3. Tried to format and delete the partition to try a clean install using `format fs=ntfs` and `delete volume override` but it also returned error `The system cannot find the file specified`.

What can I do in this situation? Data on this partition is not important and I am ready to format and do a clean Windows installation.

Please assist!

Comment: Do we talk about SSD disk?

Comment: Yes, it is an SSD drive.

Comment: For the this SSD is out. Replace it and then reinstall the Windows.

Comment: Try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the disk.

Comment: @harrymc, even if the OP recover partition and (eventually) files the disk will fail again. This happen to me twice...

Comment: Can I run TestDisk via bootable USB?

Comment: @UzairA.: There is a Live rescue CD.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: This was due to a power outage, so might just be one unfortunate occasion.

Comment: @harrymc, cross my fingers, but the power outage can happen because of the SSD too

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Cross my finger, too.